# How can I integrate my JSP page into my web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I want to write a web service using my jsp pages. Later I want to  call it in my Android program. How can I do that? I want to know how to create a web service for a JSP page?

Comment: Sneha, Your question is not clear (to humble me, at least). Edit your question and answer me this "What system component(s) do you want to call from what system component(s)". To me "I want to write a web service using my jsp pages." sounds like you want to write a web-service which returns the (formatted contents) of your JSP pages, which (prima facie) is a BAD design. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Your question isn't communicating sensibly. Your design should be use webservice from a controller/service layer of your app.

Comment: Do you want to create such JSP pages which can be accessed as WebServices from your Android app?

Comment: yeah. I want to create such JSP pages which can be accessed as WebServices from your Android app.Exactly I want to write a web-service which returns the formatted contents of your JSP pages so that I can display images easily in my android web service call.

Comment: @Snesha: then why produce a webservice? Why not simply request the URL of that JSP from your Android program? Or more directly: what exactly do you mean by "webservice"? Are you talking about SOAP/HTTP+WSDL or are you talking about "a service that can be called via the web"?

Comment: yeah. I meant SOAP/HTTP+WSDL. Yeah I can request the URL but if some Database (MySQL) program is also associated with it, can i do that?

Comment: yeah... I am going through your solution  GEEkGUy.

Answer (score 0):

Sneha

Form last tow week i am doing RnD on same this topic.. and after all i got solution.. but the different is i am using php...

This is one type of login system that using remote db as mysql and in between webpage like jsp/php

Servlet:- http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/

Still if you have any question about this mail me on ajaypatel_aj@ayhaoo.com.

Comment: This is really a useful. Good one on login screen. Thanks buddy.